# How do you force compiler to pass some variable by reference in C++?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Here is a simple example;

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {}

std::string str("some huge text");
foo(str);
```

My question is how can I force the compiler to pass str by reference
without modifying function foo?

Comment: If `foo` wasn't coded to handle a reference, why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Mat: Strictly speaking, it's coded neither to handle a reference nor a non-reference. The type of its only parameter is dependent on a template parameter. (Of course, you're right with the implication that you'd usually see `T& t` in the function template parameter list if it were intended to be used in this manner.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801843/can-it-cause-problems-to-explicitly-pass-a-reference-into-a-function-template-tha

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass the reference type explicitly:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {}

int main() {
   std::string str("some huge text");
   foo<std::string&>(str);
}
```

This *does* modify the function instantiation that you get (by generating a `void foo<std::string&>(std::string& t)`), but it doesn't modify the function template.

### [Live demo.](http://codepad.org/u3njLTio)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the answer I've been looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass template argument deduction and explicitly pass `std::string&`.

Comment: I guess using `std::ref` is another option.

Comment: @Ben: [You'd have to modify the function body](http://www.ideone.com/rulg4) to call `.get()` in order to use the ref perfectly transparently.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answers, you can also think to overload `foo()`:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {}

void foo(std::string &t) {}

std::string str("some huge text");
foo(str);
```

This way you don't change the actual `foo()` behavior and get your work done with the overloaded version.

Comment: Is there a rule specifying the compiler to use the reference version of `foo()`? I kind of think the compiler would still go with the pass by value version of `foo()`.

Comment: @SamuelLi, compiler chooses first the overloaded version which matches the best. By default a parameter is passed by reference or const reference or value. Since we are receiving the parameter by reference, it will be selected. The template case is selected if nothing else is left. Extending to this discussion, if derive `std::string` to `MyString` and then pass it, then `foo(std::string&)` is not selected even though it's a matching base. But it rather chooses the template.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, thanks for explaining it. I was thinking the case where you explicit instantiate a version of `foo(T t)` with the templated type being a reference type, something like `template void foo( std::string& );`. It doesn't seem this version is going to be invoked...

Comment: I'm specifically thinking why [this](https://gist.github.com/shaomeng/d3749e20588e76d3c406b916446652f2) code won't compile...

Answer (score 0):

boost::reference_wrapper should also solve your problem.