# Can it cause problems to explicitly pass a reference into a function template that's not expecting one?

Tags: c++, templates, reference

There was [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800824/how-do-you-force-compiler-to-pass-some-variable-by-reference-in-c) regarding passing taking the following function template, and **instantiating it with a by-reference string parameter**:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {}
```

The answer was, of course, to give the argument explicitly:

```
int main() {
   std::string str("some huge text");
   foo<std::string&>(str);
}
```

<sup>(As an aside, there was a suggestion about using deduction and passing C++0x's `std::ref(str)`, but this requires the use of `.get()` inside the function, and the OP's requirement was transparency.)</sup>

However, IMO there can be little doubt that **the author of the function template intended for the argument to be passed by value**, or he would have written:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T& t) {}
```

<sup>(It's possible that he deliberately intended for either to be possible, but this seems unlikely to me for some reason.)</sup>

- Are there any "reasonable" scenarios where passing a reference into `foo<T>`, where the author of `foo` had *intended* the function always to take its argument by value, may cause problems?
- The answer I'm looking for most likely consists of a function body for `foo`, where the use of a reference type for `T` leads to unexpected/undesirable semantics when compared to the use of a value type for `T`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider that it's common to write algorithms like this:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
void dosomething(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, otherparams) {
    while (first != last) {
        do the work;
        ++first;
    }
}
```

It's also how the standard algorithms are implemented both in GCC and in the old SGI STL.

If `first` is taken by reference then it will be modified, so certainly there are plenty of template functions out there that will "go wrong" with reference template arguments. In this example, `first` is changed to a value equal to `last`. In another implementation, or in the next release, it might be copied and not modified at all. That's "unexpected/undesirable semantics".

Whether you call this a "problem" or not, I'm not sure. It's not the behavior that the author of the function intended, and it's probably not documented what happens to `first` if it's passed by reference (it isn't for the standard algorithms).

For the standard algorithms I think it's UB, so the caller is at fault. The standard says that the template argument should be an iterator, and while `T*` or some library iterator is an iterator type, `T* &` or reference-to-library-iterator isn't.

As long as authors of template functions have documented the requirements of their template arguments clearly, I suspect that *typically* it will just fall out in the same way as for standard algorithms and iterators -- reference types are not valid template arguments, and hence the caller is at fault. In cases where the requirements are very simple (a couple of expressions with specified behavior), a reference type probably isn't ruled out, but again as long as the function doesn't say that it *doesn't* modify the argument, and doesn't say *how* it modifies the argument, callers should consider that since it's not documented how the argument is modified, then it's unspecified. If they call the function with a reference type, and get surprised whether or how the argument is modified, again it's the caller's fault.

I expect that under-documented functions are at risk of a dispute whose fault it is when it goes wrong, though, since sometimes it'll rely on quite a close reading.

Answer (score 7):

If the programmer decided to be lazy, and use the input parameter as a temporary variable to calculate the output, then you would get problematic results:

```
template <class T>
T power2n(T a, int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) 
    {
       a *= a; 
    }
    return a;
}
```

Now if I pass the first parameter by reference, its value gets messed up.

Not saying this is good programming, just saying it happens.

Comment: Makes sense. In this case I can see it more as a honest mistake (this code would be perfectly sane were `power2n` not a template) than being lazy.